# Django Render To String for html email template not working

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to send a stylized email to a new customer once they submit a payment on my website. I read somewhere to try the render to string method which I did. The email triggers correctly, the only problem is that it doesn't seem to be using the email template. It's a basic plain text email.

Please see my code below. Any help on how to make this work would be great.

Django view code

```
notice_html = render_to_string('MY_app/email-template.html')
subject = 'Your New Design Confirmation'
from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
recipient_list = [request.POST.get('email')]
message = "A curated message based on the design the customer purchased."
send_mail(
    subject=subject, message=message,
    recipient_list=recipient_list,
    from_email=from_email, fail_silently=False
)
```

Html in template

```
<div class="email-message">
    {{ send_mail.message }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide `html_message` to [**`send_mail()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail)), and also add the message as context to [**`render_to_string()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) to use the message in template:

```
message = "A curated message based on the design the customer purchased."
# Add the message to render_to_string to use it in template
notice_html = render_to_string(
    'MY_app/email-template.html',
    { "message": message }
)
...

send_mail(
    subject=subject, 
    message=message, 
    recipient_list=recipient_list, 
    from_email=from_email, 
    fail_silently=False,
    html_message=notice_html ⬅️
)
```

.**html**:

```
<div class="email-message">
    {{ message }}
</div>
```

Or use [**`EmailMultiAlternatives`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types)):

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives, get_connection

# By default fail_silently is already False
connection = get_connection(fail_silently=False)

message = "A curated message based on the design the customer purchased."
notice_html = render_to_string('MY_app/email-template.html', { "message": message })
subject = 'Your New Design Confirmation'

email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject=subject,
    body=message,
    from_email=from_email
    to=recipient_list,
    connection=connection
)
email.attach_alternative(notice_html, "text/html")
email.send()
```

Comment: I tried the emailmultialternatives and that didnt work because I wasnt sure which context to include. I'll try this and report back. Thank you for the help.

Comment: So the solution worked but what I have in the email template the CSS styling isn't displaying?

Comment: @Vandle0, In email template you have to use internal or inline styles. Did you try to use: `<p style="color:red">{{ message }}</p>` or internal `<head><style>.email-message {color: red;}</style></head>`.

Comment: I thought it was possibly because my site is still on a local machine and not on a production server. I started using inline styles just now and it worked. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Wait @NKSM what about delivering static images like a logo file?

Comment: @Vandle0, You can still use your images `<img src="full path">` of files `<a href="full path">`. Note, you have to use full path: **`http://www.example.com/static/img/logo.png`**.  And of course you can attach a file: `email.attach_file('attachment.pdf')`.